# land IndexRoute after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm writing SPA app with React-Router.

**Question:** *how to make my app land on IndexRoute after refresh from `signIn` path?*

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={History}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Index} />
            <Route path="signIn" component={SignIn} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

**P.S.** Currently I do not handle `404` on client, server returns `404` for `<my_domain>/signIn`

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

Your server *must* be able to render the client app for any URLs that need to be "refreshable". This is just how browsers work — accessing a URL sends a GET request to that URL, and the server has to respond before the client can do any work.

Comment: Are you speaking about isomorphic apps? My server can't render views, since it 's written on Java and My client on React

Comment: No, that's unrelated. Your server should do the same thing on other URLs that it does on / — send the React application to the client. React Router will take over from there.